# SQL Server Management Studio 19 cannot create project files with a path longer than 260 characters, already enabled registry

Tags: path, ssms

I am using SQL Server Management Studio 19. When I try to create a project file within a folder it fails with:

[image: Create project fails]

The path is only 170 characters. However, I had enabled long paths on the system by means of registry key and rebooted the computer. I can create files, folders inside that path and edit a word document having a path of more than 260 characters (I tried 350 and it works). So long paths were correctly enabled, even as I am not using them:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled' -Value 1

Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem' -Name 'LongPathsEnabled'


LongPathsEnabled : 1
PSPath           : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem
PSParentPath     : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control
PSChildName      : FileSystem
PSDrive          : HKLM
PSProvider       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

By the way, the folder is in OneDrive.

Any ideas? Maybe related to utf8/double char encoding?

Comment: There is no such thing as SSMS 2019; do you mean SSMS 18, released in 2019, or SSMS 19, released in 2022.

Comment: You are right, I mean 19. Editing.